# Tkinter.grid spacing options?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, grid-layout

I'm new to Tkinter, and I tried creating an app with the grid layout manager. However, I can't seem to find a way to utilize it the way I want to. What I need to do is simulate a grid full of 'cells' so that I can place, for example, a label in cell (3,8) or a button in cell (5,1). Here is an example of what I've tried:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text = 'Label')
label.grid(column = 3, row = 8)

button = tk.Button(root, text = 'Button')
button.grid(column = 5, row = 1)
```

Tkinter keeps the relative position of each widget (i.e. `button` is above and to the right of `label`), but it ignores any space in between. I've searched a bit for this problem and found out about `weight`, but that doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for; I'd like something independent of the `label` and `button`'s layouts. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can specify the spacing on columns/rows in the grid (including those that contain no widget) by running the [`grid_columnconfigure`](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_columnconfigure-method) and [`grid_rowconfigure`](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_rowconfigure-method) methods on the parent of the widgets (in this case, the parent would be `root`).

For example, to set a minimum width for the 4th column, add the last line to your code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text = 'Label')
label.grid(column = 3, row = 8)

button = tk.Button(root, text = 'Button')
button.grid(column = 5, row = 1)

root.grid_columnconfigure(4, minsize=100)  # Here
```

If you want to set a minimum size for all of your columns and rows, you can iterate through them all using:

```
col_count, row_count = root.grid_size()

for col in xrange(col_count):
    root.grid_columnconfigure(col, minsize=20)

for row in xrange(row_count):
    root.grid_rowconfigure(row, minsize=20)
```

**Edit** Interestingly, effbot states:

> minsize=Defines the minimum size for the row. *Note that if a row is completely empty, it will not be displayed, even if this option is set.*

(italics mine) but it seems to work even for rows and columns that are empty, as far as I've tried.

Comment: "NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined". Should just be range()

Comment: @RussellStrauss The code is for python 2. You are running it on python 3

Answer (score 7):

By default, a row is of height zero and a column is of width zero. So, rows and columns that don't have anything in them will be invisible and take up no space.

Comment: Unless we don't set the _minsize_ property of the grid for that particular column or row. So, what is in the _effbot_ is wrong (according to the other answer), right?